# Which kinds of equations of elementary functions can have elementary solutions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions, differential-algebra

Which kinds of zeroing equations of elementary functions can have solutions which are elementary numbers or explicit elementary numbers?

Take the equation

$$F(x)=0,$$

wherein $F$ is an elementary function.

[Looking if F is elementary invertible](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320801/how-to-extend-ritts-theorem-on-elementary-invertible-bijective-elementary-funct) is not the whole answer.

The [Elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) are the functions which are generated from one variable by finite nesting of algebraic functions, $\exp$ and/or $\ln$.

The field of the [Elementary numbers (Liouville numbers)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Closed-form_number) is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ generated by $\mathbb{Q}$ that is **algebraically closed** under $\exp$ and $\ln$. The field of the [Explicit elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Closed-form_number) is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ generated by $\mathbb{Q}$ that is **closed** under $\exp$ and $\ln$. They are defined i.a. in [Lin 1983] and [Chow 1999] respectively.

[Lin 1983] and [Chow 1999] give an answer for exponential polynomials. They prove that the irreducible polynomials $P\in\mathbb{\overline{Q}}[x,e^x]$ involving both $x$ and $e^x$ cannot have solutions that are elementary numbers and explicit elementary numbers respectively.

My questions:

**Are there answers for further classes of functions?**

**Can the methods of Lin and Chow be used for further classes of functions?**

There is at least a hint. Chow writes: "The reader may check that our arguments generalize readily to other transcendental equations such as $x=cos\ x$."

If his method can be applied to the equation $x=cos\ x$, could it perhaps be applied also for the functions $R\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(x,t_1,...,t_n)$, wherein $1<n\leq 14$, $t_1=\exp(x)$, $t_2=\exp(xi)$, $t_3=\sin(x)$, $t_4=\cos(x)$, $t_5=\tan(x)$, $t_6=\cot(x)$ $t_7=\sec(x)$, $t_8=\csc(x)$, $t_9=\sinh(x)$, $t_{10}=\cosh(x)$, $t_{11}=\tanh(x)$, $t_{12}=\coth(x)$, $t_{13}=\text{sech}(x)$, $t_{14}=\text{csh}(x)$?

$\ $

[[Chow 1999] Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)

[[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43836165)